# uninstall/re-install of poetry package manager not working due to missing pyvenv.config

Tags: python, pyvenv

OS: Windows 11, Python version: 3.10.3

Initial poetry install via Powershell command:
`(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://install.python-poetry.org -UseBasicParsing).Content | python -`

Had some problems with initial install, so ran uninstall with no problems. However, on attempting to reinstall, got the following message:

```
Installing Poetry (1.1.13)
Installing Poetry (1.1.13): Creating environment
Actual environment location may have moved due to redirects, links or junctions.
  Requested location: "C:\Users\321gp\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
  Actual location:    "C:\Users\321gp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
Actual environment location may have moved due to redirects, links or junctions.
  Requested location: "C:\Users\321gp\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
  Actual location:    "C:\Users\321gp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
Installing Poetry (1.1.13): An error occurred. Removing partial environment.
Poetry installation failed.
See C:\Users\321gp\poetry-installer-error-2yr835li.log for error logs.
```

Error log contains the following:

```
No pyvenv.cfg file

Traceback:

  File "<stdin>", line 879, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 515, in run
  File "<stdin>", line 536, in install
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "<stdin>", line 608, in make_env
  File "<stdin>", line 594, in make_env
  File "<stdin>", line 326, in make
  File "<stdin>", line 349, in pip
  File "<stdin>", line 346, in python
  File "<stdin>", line 339, in run
```

Checking the links listed, `C:\Users\... \Roaming\pypoetry\venv\` does not exist.

Suggestions on how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in Windows this command does not have yet an uninstall. I think the best way to do it is the manual way:
Just go to the folder:

> C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Roaming\

and locate poetry folder. It could be more folders. Delete them and then
type in PS console to make sure :

> PS > poetry

You should get some message:

*The term 'poetry' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.*